# JQuery event when checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, alert

I'm having trouble getting an event to happen when a checkbox is checked. I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

**My Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#ch_price').is(':checked')) {
    alert ("Yes");
  }
} );
```

How would I get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is not in the code you posted. It looks like you're using the `.live()` method somewhere, which was deprecated in jQuery 1.9 (http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed).

Comment: Might be code elsewhere on the page, then. The code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/AH5bk/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using a newer version of jQuery. You can either downgrade jQuery or replace `live` with `on` .

Answer (score 0):

Have you used live method anywhere in your code.

[.live](/questions/tagged/.live) was removed in JQuery 1.9

See document? 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Which Version of **JQuery** are you using?

Comment: In your HTML file which version of **JQuery** have you included

for Ex


`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: try `$('#ch_price').attr('checked', true);`instead of `($('#ch_price').is(':checked')`

Comment: Ive just added: $('#ch_price').attr('checked', true); but now the alert happens on page load and when I check the box after that alert has been dismissed nothing happens.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is automatically selecting the checkbox too.

Comment: because in HTML checkbox is by default Checked, 

The defaultChecked property returns the default value of the checked attribute.

Comment: My HTML is fine as its just three checkboxes at the moment. However I managed to achieve the effect that I wanted using: $('#ch_price_check').change(function() { });